# Codeigniter's zip download files are empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page where users can choose which files they want to download from different jobs.  There could be several files for each job.  When the form is submitted, the files are sent to a function that should zip them in the different job folders and then zip the whole lot and download it.

Everything is working great except that when I go into each folder in the downloaded zip file, it shows me that there is an array in there, but it's empty.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the function:

```
public function downloadDocFiles() {
    $postdata = $this->input->post();
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->load->library('awss3', null, 'S3');
    foreach ($postdata['files'] as $key => $value) {
        $d = $this->S3->readFile('uploads/' . $key . '/' . $value, true);
        $this->zip->add_data($key . '/' . $value, $d);
    }
    $this->zip->download('Completed Jobs.zip');
}
```

The data comes through as:

```
Array
    (
        [files] => Array
            (
                [3454] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => file1.docx
                        [1] => file2.docx
                    )

                [2711] => Array
                   (
                        [0] => nameoffile.docx
                   )

                [1162] => Array
                   (
                        [0] => zyx3.docx
                        [1] => iure8.docx
                   )

             )

)
```

The file, Completed Jobs.zip is downloaded and has folders inside it (3454, 2711 and 1162) but those folders just contain 'Array', size 0.

Comment: have you made sure if the files actually contain data that you trying to save before writing and then creating a zip file ?

Comment: @OmarAbbas, yes, they do contain data. The jobs are all jobs that have been completed, so they definitely are not empty.

Comment: ok, but it seems like your zip files are creating ok, with all the files and folders, but they do not contain any data ? like array is empty when you read the file ? is that right ?

Comment: Yes, correct.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: `var_dump()` the write content before you create a file and see the result.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Omas Abbas for the help.

I changed my code to this and it worked:

```
public function downloadDocFiles() {
    $postdata = $this->input->post();
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->load->library('awss3', null, 'S3');
    foreach ($postdata['files'] as $key => $value) {
        $count = count($postdata['files'][$key]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $d = $this->S3->readFile('uploads/' . $key . '/' . $value[$i], true);
            $this->zip->add_data($key . '/' . $value[$i], $d);
        }
    }
    $this->zip->download('Completed Jobs.zip');
}
```